# Makefile variable expansion syntax

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu

Please explain how does this TARGET get expanded?

```
PROJECT=helloworld
TARGET = $(PROJECT:=.so)
```

For example, I have generated helloworld.so.1.2.3, helloworld.so.1 and helloworld.so

Comment: To `helloworld.so`. Value of `PROJECT` replacing `''` at the end with `,so'. [See](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html)

Comment: what is the benefit comparing to using $(PROJECT).so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would get messy in the comments, reiterating the description from [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html) with this example. For:

```
PROJECT=helloworld
TARGET = $(PROJECT:=.so)
```

Value of `$(TARGET)` would be `helloworld.so`. As an empty string `''` at the end of the word would gets replaced with `.so`. This "end of a word" is the difference from:

```
TARGET = $(PROJECT).so
```

With `PROJECT` being `helloworld`, the resulting value would look the same, but call `make PROJECT="hello world"` and in case of the former you end up with `hello.so` and `world.so` in `TARGET`, for the latter, it would be `"hello world.so"`. Or to quote the docs:

> `$(var:a=b)’` ... replace every `a` at the end of a word with `b` ... “at the end of a word”, we mean that `a` must appear either followed by whitespace or at the end of the value in order to be replaced

Comment: Thanks, i read := as a variable expansion but it should be  :""=.

Comment: There is another difference: if `$(PROJECT)` had trailing spaces they would be preserved by `$(PROJECT).so` (`helloworld .so`) but not by `$(PROJECT:=.so)`. This can be tested with `NULL :=` and then `PROJECT := helloworld $(NULL)`.